# compare doubles that are from a parsed JSON using GSON

Tags: android, json, double, gson

Is double that is gotten from a json with Gson is constant and could be compared to a double (from same orgin) with simple `"==","=!"`.

The double is a price for a item(that is 0 or decimal number X.XX), that is compared to a different price.

Or should I use `Double.compare(x,y) or x/3==y/3`, or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is better to use [BigDecimal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in your case.

Another way is selecting precision and doing next comparison

```
public static final double PRECISION = 0.001;

if (Math.abs(x-y) < PRECISION) {
    //x is equal to y
}
```